# Brute force script stops working at 26 words for some reason

Tags: python, testing, brute-force

I tried to make a quick python dictionary bruteforcer to bruteforce a zip file. Although it stops bruteforcing at 26 words for some reason??

CODE:

```py
# Author: drk 
# A quick zipfile brute forcer (dictionary)

import zipfile
from tqdm import tqdm

wordlist = "/home/drk/Desktop/list.txt"

zip_file = "/home/drk/Desktop/impossible-password.zip"

file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)

count = input("\nDo you want to count the amount of words? (y/n): ")
if count == "y":
    total = len(list(open(wordlist, 'rb')))
    print("\nTotal words is: " + str(total))
elif count == "n":
    print("ok")
else:
    print("did not recognize input, continuing...")

with open(wordlist, "rb") as list:
    for word in tqdm(wordlist, total=total, unit="words"):
        try:
            file.extractall(pwd=word.strip())
        except:
            continue
        else:
            print("[+] Password Found!: " + word.decode().strip())
print("[-] None of the passwords did work. ")
```

OUTPUT:

```
Do you want to count the amount of words? (y/n): y

Total words is: 100000
0%|                                                            | 26/100000 [00:00<00:05, 18968.85words/s]
[-] None of the passwords did work.
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Side-note: Don't name your variables `list`; cutting off access to the `list` constructor in that scope is bad form.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the string `wordlist`, which is 26 characters long. It seems like what you want to do is iterate the lines of the file, which you have opened as `list`. Replace your `tqdm` call with

```
tqdm(list, total=total, unit="words")
```

Comment: Corollary: They almost certainly intended to use (the poorly named) `list` instead.